# Installing Ruby on Rails on Ubuntu or Mint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, installation

I have installed Rails on my Windows 7 partition, but it is so slow, so I decided to try to install it on Linux.

I have tried Ubuntu 11.04 and Mint 12, and for both, I get the same problem.

I am following the guide "Ruby On Rails Tutorial", and I also have a PDF installation guide called "Ruby On Rails Ubuntu Linux Mint.

I get to the part where it says `type rvm notes` - which lists stuff to install. I then install all that stuff, and then when I type `rvm` it says "there is no rvm". Clearly, there was an rvm for me to type `rvm notes`.

I have searched the drive (sudo find / -name *rvm*, and I get
11 entries, including /etc/profie.d/rvm.sh and /etc/rvmrc. There is also a `ruby-rvm`.

I gave myself a little time to test Django and Ruby, but I seem to be getting nowhere with Ruby.

I am about to try the Turnkey Ubuntu Rails installation in Virtual Box, but I would still like to know why I cannot install it in Ubuntu or Mint. I suspect it is the same problem on both.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not tried this lately but it seems up to date and I trust Ryan Biggs. See his [post on installing Ruby & Rails on Ubuntu](http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/) and I'm sure you'll figure it out.

Comment: I found that link after I posted my message and yes it worked on Ubuntu 11.10. But you need to add 'sudo apt-get install nodejs nodejs-dev' once you finish the instructions from Ryan Biggs.

Comment: Yes, if you're installing nodejs, or perhaps want to use CoffeeScript. If my answer is correct you should mark it.